# Formatting pandas dataframe to publish to Zenodo description

Tags: html, pandas, zenodo

I am using the [Zenodo REST API](https://developers.zenodo.org/#representation) to upload data and I would like to include a table in the `description`. The website states `description` attribute can be `html`.

My metadata is stored in a pandas dataframe, so I first tried using the `to_html()` function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['metadata', 'to', 'publish'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['item1'])
df.to_html(header=False)
```

This output string is filled with many, many carriage returns (not sure why) and this does not work (see [here](https://sandbox.zenodo.org/record/840422#.YLDx5ZNKhBw)).

> '\n  \n    \n      a\n      metadata\n    \n    \n      b\n      to\n    \n    \n      c\n      publish\n    \n  \n'

This is an example I have tried.

[image]

I have tried a number of other options including `to_markdown()` and `to_string()` but none have worked well.

My question is: how can I format a pandas dataframe as a table that can be displayed in a Zenodo `description`?

Comment: Ahh OK tables are coming https://github.com/zenodo/zenodo/issues/2147#issue-839765443